# Throwing SQLDataReader Errors Upwards

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, error-handling, sqlclient

I have a basic class for filling some properties using SqlDataReader.  Additionally, there is a class for doing type conversions (SConvert) and filling the object.  The SqlDataReader retrieves data but, somewhere in the type conversions there is a problem, probably requesting a field by the wrong name.  The problem I'm having is that the error get's caught way up in the 'FindAll' method and has no meaningful information.  I would like to get meaningful errors thrown up from the SConvert class *(e.g. something more than ' Object reference not set to an instance of an object.')* and be told which field is being requested incorrectly.

Any ideas to start me on the path to getting this figured out would be very much appreciated.

I put three comments in the code '// <--...' that indicate where the error is being caught, the spelling error, and what should be thrown to the top.

```
public class People
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public static List<People> FindAll()
        {
            List<People> pl = new List<DataService.People>();

            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("MyConnectionString"))
                {
                    sqlConnection.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("MyStoredProc", sqlConnection))
                    {
                        sqlCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
                        while (sqlDataReader.Read())
                        {
                            People p = readData(sqlDataReader);
                            pl.Add(p);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { throw new System.ArgumentException(ex.Message); } // <--EXCEPTION GETS CAUGHT HERE ***
            return pl;
        }

        private static People readData(SqlDataReader sqlDataReader)
        {
            People p = null;
            SConvert sc = new DataService.SConvert(sqlDataReader);
            p = new DataService.People()
            {
                FirstName = sc.SToString("FirstNme"), // <--SPELLING ERROR HERE
                LastName = sc.SToString("LastName"),
                Age = sc.SToInt("Age")
            };
            return p;
        }
    }
```

The conversions:

```
public class SConvert
    {
        private SqlDataReader sqlr;
        public SConvert(SqlDataReader sqlDataReader) { sqlr = sqlDataReader; }
        public string SToString(string FieldName)
        {
            try { return sqlr[FieldName].ToString(); }
            catch { throw new System.ArgumentException(string.Format("Error in SConvert when converting string value for field: {0}", FieldName)); } // <--I WANT THIS EXCEPTION THROWN UP TO THE TOP (SEE ***)
        }
        public int SToInt(string FieldName)
        {
            try { return (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sqlr[FieldName].ToString())) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(sqlr[FieldName].ToString()); }
            catch { throw new System.ArgumentException(string.Format("Error in SConvert when converting int value for field: {0}", FieldName)); }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you doing `catch (Exception ex) { throw new System.ArgumentException(ex.Message); }` ? It's not an `ArgumentException`, and you're wiping out the original stack trace, exception class, and any other details. Just remove that `try/catch`.

Comment: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" means it's NRE, you should include `throw new NullReferenceException("message")` on catch clause. You can catch multiple exceptions by using if-condition and set exception message to be shown when error occurred.